# Get this method to convert Excel to PDF running with a button

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I just followed this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17574/Programmatically-Convert-Documents-to-PDFs-the-Eas) on how to convert Excel documents to PDF ad now have:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Stage
{
    public partial class Factuur : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreatePdf("action","factuur.xls","img");
        }
            public static string GetDefaultPrinterName()
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            return pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        }
        public static long SetDefaultPrinterName(string name)
        {
            return SetDefaultPrinterName(name);
        }

        public static void CreatePdf(string action, string file, string directory)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith("xls"))
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                excel.Visible = false;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(directory, file),
                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                workbook.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 1, false, Type.Missing,
                                false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                excel.Quit();
            }
            else
            {
                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo.FileName = file;
                p.StartInfo.Verb = action;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Starting process");
                p.Start();
                //p.Kill();
                //}
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Pdf");
                CreatePdf(file);
            }
        }
        private static string CreatePdf(string fileName)
        {
            string command = "gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\"" +
                    fileName + ".pdf\"  -fc:\\output.ps";

            Console.WriteLine(command);
            Process p = new Process();

            StreamWriter sw;
            StreamReader sr;

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
            info.WorkingDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            Console.WriteLine("Current directory: " + info.WorkingDirectory);
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;

            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            sw = p.StandardInput;
            sr = p.StandardOutput;
            sw.AutoFlush = true;

            sw.WriteLine(command);

            sw.Close();

            string ret = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(ret);
            return ret;
        }
        }

    }
```

As you can see I tried using a button to get all the stuff going but that returns this error:

> "An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred
>   in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: System can't find the path of the file."

Any idea how I can get this stuff working by clicking on the button?

Copy pasting the whole method in the button doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked the file path? Is it correct?

Comment: You set the working directory to "img/factuur.xls", which is not a directory

Comment: Oh ye right, still got the same stuff tho.